# Pandas round is truncating in some cases

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rounding, truncate

I am using the following code and as you can see in the 2nd row, the rounding is correct while in the 3rd row, the data is being truncated.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [[11,10],[17.50,11.01],[21.95,22.5]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['A','B'])

df['avg'] = df[["A", "B"]].mean(axis=1)
df['avg_round'] = df['avg'].apply(lambda x: np.round(x, decimals=2))
```

[image]

I have tried this as well and the results are identical:

```
df['avg] = df[["A", "B"]].mean(axis=1).round(2)
```

Comment: Isn't this just a display issue? the values are correct, it's just not displaying the trailing zeroes

Comment: No, 22.225 should be rounded up to 22.23 but it's here it's 22.22

Comment: @NikhilRatnaShakya: `22.225` should indeed be rounded up to `22.23`, but not for the reasons you think. Pandas (and NumPy, and Python) is using a _binary_ floating-point format. What looks like `22.225` is actually being stored as `22.22500000000000142108547152020037174224853515625`. Since that's strictly greater than `22.225`, it should indeed round up. NumPy/Pandas does not do perfectly correct rounding here, but it's unwise to depend on the results of a decimal representation of a binary approximation to a decimal round of a binary approximation to a decimal halfway case in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a pandas issue. Look at the actual values of `avg`:

```
>>> df['avg'][1] 
   14.254999999999999
>>> df['avg'][2]
   22.225000000000001
```

If you use:

```
df['avg_round'] = df['avg'].apply(lambda x: round(x, 2))
```

You will get `14.25` and `22.23` - one is rounded up and one down, due to the floating point representation. Numpy's round however will give you `14.26` and `22.22`, because it rounds towards the nearest *even* number in cases such as these. As pointed out in the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.around.html#numpy.around):

> For values exactly halfway between rounded decimal values, NumPy
>   rounds to the nearest even value. Thus 1.5 and 2.5 round to 2.0, -0.5
>   and 0.5 round to 0.0, etc. Results may also be surprising due to the
>   inexact representation of decimal fractions in the IEEE floating point
>   standard [R1011] and errors introduced when scaling by powers of ten.

Comment: I tried this with the mean of [22.5,21.99] which is 22.245 and ended up with 22.24. The number was being stored as 22.244999999999997. I tried rounding to 4 digits and then again to 2 and it worked. However, I am unsure if it is the right way.

Comment: @NikhilRatnaShakya - This is the expected behavior of numpy's round. If you don't like the way it works, use ceil.

Comment: round-to-even is irrelevant here: it only applies to exact ties, and this isn't one: the actual value stored for `22.225` is almost certainly `22.22500000000000142108547152020037174224853515625`, which would be rounded _up_ by a `round` function that does correct rounding. NumPy's `round` function does not do correct rounding. Python's, however, does, and in pure Python you'll get `round(22.225, 2)` giving `22.23`.